# Understanding a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I’m having trouble understanding a set I’m currently working with and would appreciate any help.

The set in question is R = {($x^5,x^4$) | x element Irrational Numbers} $R \subset Q x Q$

Comment: Are you looking for an irrational number $x$ such that $x^4, x^5 \in \Bbb Q$?  If $x^4$ and $x^5$ both are rational, then so is their quotient.  So yes, if that is your definition of $R$, then $R = \varnothing$.  Your reasoning is not correct, though, because you have no basis for saying $x^5=x$.  In fact, because $x \notin \Bbb Q$ but $x^5 \in \Bbb Q$, you know that $x \neq x^5$.

Comment: The tags `[elementary-set-theory]` and `[set-theory]` are almost never both appropriate. Please read the description of a tag before adding it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for an irrational number $x$ such that $x^4, x^5 \in \Bbb Q$?  If $x^4$ and $x^5$ both are rational, then so is their quotient.  So yes, if that is your definition of $R$, then $R = \varnothing$.

Your reasoning is not correct, though, because you have no basis for saying $x^5=x$.  In fact, because $x \notin \Bbb Q$ but $x^5 \in \Bbb Q$, you know that $x \neq x^5$.